# How to use Visual Studio "attach to running container" with Rancher desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, rancher, vscode-remote

I replaced docker on my machine with Rancher desktop using dockerd/moby container engine. In Visual Studio Code I used to be able to click "Attach to running container", find my docker container, and open it. Now, when I click "Attach to running container" I get "Docker version 17.12.0 or later required." Is it possible to use this tool with rancher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this issue on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4873, you should try to install:

- VS Code Remote-Containers extension v0.169.0
- VS Code Insiders from this link https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/